# Sorting Alphanumeric Data By using orderBy

Tags: html, angularjs, sorting

Am trying to sort the `ng-options` data by using `orderBy` , My data contains both alphabets and string's .  i can able to solve this`["A10","B2","C1"]` kind of data's, My question here in how to sort this`["1","2","10","a","b","C"]` kind of data's ? Is it possible to do this ! . Searched in many sites but didn't get any ideas so someone help me or clarify me from this .
Here is my working code,

```
ng-options="option.id as option.roomno for option in MyData 
   | unique:'roomno' | orderBy:'roomno' "
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kveynz43/1/)

I have updated your code but observed that you need to convert given array to json array so that in ng-options you can sort it.

and about unique you need to use third party library for it.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in data | orderBy: 'name' " ng-model="test">
{{item.name}}
</select>
</div> 
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
$scope.data = [
{name:'abc'},
{name:'test'},
{name:'xyz'}
];
// this will not work 
//$scope.data = ["1","2","10","a","b","C"];
});
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy . Here am having one doubt !

Comment: `$scope.data = [
{name:'abc'},
{name:'10'},
{name:'2'}
];`   My expected output is 2,10,abc but actual was 10,2,abc .. What's the reason ?

Comment: Yes it is because of datatype and it is string so it will check from 0 to 9 at first element and if you want to make it happen the need to change number rather than string for roomno

Comment: Ok fine , If i change that into number means what about the strings ? How they will be sorted !! any idea buddy ?

Comment: Same as alphabates first will be number and then alphabates

Comment: Can i have the Example for that buddy ? Which is having the combo of alphabates and numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a custom `orderBy` function:

```
ng-options="option.id as option.roomno for option in MyData 
   | unique:'roomno' | orderBy: orderAlphanumeric "

//Controller
$scope.orderAlphanumeric = function(item) {
  // do some data wrangling
  return something;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud. Can i have any jsfiddle ,plunker link's for that ?

Comment: @jayant patil has answered above